# Webkit @font-face not working properly

Tags: fonts, webkit, font-face

**`fonts.css`**:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntu';
    src: url('../fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntu-bold';
    src: url('../fonts/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntu-medium';
    src: url('../fonts/Ubuntu-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntu-mediumitalic';
    src: url('../fonts/Ubuntu-MediumItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

The elements get the correct `font-family` attribute, however the styles are messed up. For example `ubuntu-medium` gets displayed as regular weight, and `ubuntu-bold` gets displayed with medium weight fonts. I tried to set the `font-weight` property at element level and in `@font-face` too, but it did not bring success. Works properly in Chrome or Firefox. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an article on this issue: [WEBKIT (SAFARI 3.1) AND THE CSS @FONT-FACE DECLARATION](http://blog.elliottcable.name/posts/webkit_safari_3_1_and_the_css_font_face_declaration.xhtml)